# sqldependency not detecting change. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, signalr, sqldependency

Im trying to check for any database changes using sqldependency and then send something to clients that are connected to signalr. The thing is, it seems that its not detecting changes. I feel theres something missing. heres the code:

```
[HubName("DataHub")]
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    public void pushOnChange() 
    {
        string connection = "data source=fourthD;initial catalog=dash;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;";
        SqlDependency.Start(connection);
        SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(connection);
        connectionString.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.insight", connectionString))
        {
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }


    void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { };
        data.Add("Id","34");
        data.Add("DeviceId", "163-117")
        data.Add("DeviceUserName", "Someone");

        var result = new[] { data };

        Clients.All.addData(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read something first?

Comment: Also, indenting your code correctly is generally seen as a trait. Incorrectly indented code is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about the code.. any solutions?

Comment: Does SqlDependecy work in a 'disconnected' environment like a web application is? I would expect it to only work in a winform application, where you have a constantly running application.

Comment: This code seems to be no-op or very race'y. If a client calls `pushOnChange()` you create a new `SqlDependency` instance then you `ExecuteReader` and immediately after `dependency` goes out of scope which I believe will unsubscribe event handler. I would think that dependency notification happens on a different thread and (just because it used db) takes some time to execute so it is very unlikely (almost impossible) you would get the notification while the `dependency` instance is around.

Comment: I also found this: http://ruchirac.blogspot.in/2014/10/get-database-change-notification-in.html which might be helpful/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SqlDependency requires resubscription. So, you should modify your OnDependencyChange method like this:

```
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Resubscription
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.insight"
            , connectionString))
    {
        command.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
        command.ExecuteReader();
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { };
    data.Add("Id","34");
    data.Add("DeviceId", "163-117")
    data.Add("DeviceUserName", "Someone");

    var result = new[] { data };

    Clients.All.addData(result);
}
```

Hope this helps.